# knockout variable not defined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

I'm relatively new to Knockout.js and am having trouble getting this computed observable working. In short, I want to disable a button until the textarea has input. Here is the HTML:

For the textarea:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="Note" name="note" data-bind="value:text1, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" placeholder="Enter note..."></textarea>
```

For the button:

```
<btn class="btn btn-maroon" id="saveNote" href="javascript: void(0);" data-bind="enable: hasInput, click: addNoteis"><i class="icon-save"></i>Save Note</btn>
```

And here is my .js:

```
    var vm = {
        text1: ko.observable(""),
    }

    vm.hasInput = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.text1();
    }, vm);

    ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

When running in firebug, I get an error from the console that reads:

> ReferenceError: text1 is not defined

I should add that I am referencing this fiddle to create my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/oliverw/s2VmL/1/

EDIT: The "click:addNote" part of the button was for something else. I forgot to remove it in this snippet as the "addNote" functionality is working just fine. I apologize for the confusion and I thank you all for noticing it. Because of this, it appears that T.J. has answered my question. I had the bindings working improperly within the ViewModel and the bindings were causing conflict.

Comment: That's odd, I'd expect you to get a complaint about `addNote` (which you have in your bindings, but not in your VM), not `hasInput`. Your `ko.computed` is right (although I prefer KO's newer syntax).

Comment: well your code looks fine josh but only thing i seem to notice is you haven't defined `click:note` in your vm . check this its working cool here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/s2VmL/24/ . cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking at an old error message. The problem with your VM as shown in your question is that you don't have `addNote` defined anywhere, but you are trying to bind `click` to it.

If you add it and make your `btn` element an actual `button`, all is well:

```js
var vm = {
  text1: ko.observable(""),
};

vm.hasInput = ko.computed(function() {
  return this.text1();
}, vm);

vm.addNote = function() {}; // <=== Added

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control" id="Note" name="note" data-bind="value:text1, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" placeholder="Enter note..."></textarea>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-maroon" id="saveNote" href="javascript: void(0);" data-bind="click: addNote, enable: hasInput"><i class="icon-save"></i>Save Note</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: Just completely FWIW, I prefer the new syntax for `ko.computed` that's a bit more explicit:

```
vm.hasInput = ko.computed({
  owner: vm,
  read: function() {
    return this.text1();
  }
});
```

That also lets you specify `pure: true` for a [pure computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-pure.html) like yours above:

```
vm.hasInput = ko.computed({
  pure: true,
  owner: vm,
  read: function() {
    return this.text1();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, T.J. I think that did it. I had another bind on the button that was passing the data from the input to something else. That was all working just fine but was conflicting when I tried adding more to it. I restructured the VM a little and all seems to be working well. Thank you for your help! Also, I'll keep the MCVE in mind for next time.

Comment: @JoshSalazar: Glad that helped. I misunderstood why you were linking to the fiddle initially, but I get it now.

Comment: @JoshSalazar: Just added a note about `ko.computed`, just FWIW. Best,

Comment: Thank you. This helps a lot. I'll work on implementing this method instead. I've used this elsewhere in the application and I'm not sure why I didn't do it here. I guess I didn't understand the difference before. Thanks again!